# Projection to 1D

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators

Why is $\mid \psi \rangle \langle \psi \mid$ the projection to $\mathbb{C} \psi$ if $\Vert\psi\Vert =1$?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that we have a state, which we can describe as a linear combination in some basis $|\phi\rangle = \sum_m c_m |\psi_m\rangle$ with $||\psi_m||=1$ for all $m$. Acting with the projection $P_n = |\psi_n\rangle\langle\psi_n|$ will give as exactly $c_m |\psi_n\rangle$, which is what a projection should do. The resulting state lies completely in the subspace spanned by $|\psi\rangle$, and is multiplied by the coefficient of the state in the original linear representation. You can also convince yourself that $P_n^2 = P_n$ (as projecting twice onto the same space is just like projecting once), for example.